# How do I serialise a List<T> to XML using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, linq-to-xml

I've this generic list

```
   List<zil> listKD = new List<zil>
            {
            new zil{day="Mon",c="1",S1="08:00",S2="08:40",S3="08:47"},
            new zil{day="Mon",c="2",S1="08:50",S2="09:30",S3="09:37"},
            new zil{day="Mon",c="3",S1="09:40",S2="10:20",S3="10:27"},
            new zil{day="Mon",c="4",S1="10:30",S2="11:10",S3="11:17"},
            new zil{day="Tue",c="1",S1="08:00",S2="08:40",S3="08:47"},
            new zil{day="Tue",c="2",S1="08:50",S2="09:30",S3="09:37"},
            new zil{day="Wed",c="1",S1="08:00",S2="08:40",S3="08:47"},
            new zil{day="Wed",c="2",S1="08:50",S2="09:30",S3="09:37"},
            new zil{day="Thu",c="1",S1="08:00",S2="08:40",S3="08:47"},
            new zil{day="Thu",c="2",S1="08:50",S2="09:30",S3="09:37"},
            new zil{day="Thu",c="3",S1="09:40",S2="10:20",S3="10:27"},
            new zil{day="Fri",c="1",S1="08:00",S2="08:40",S3="08:47"},
            new zil{day="Fri",c="2",S1="08:50",S2="09:30",S3="09:37"},
            new zil{day="Fri",c="3",S1="09:40",S2="10:20",S3="10:27"},
            new zil{day="Fri",c="4",S1="10:30",S2="11:10",S3="11:17"},
            };
```

and I want save,this list xml but I can't like this xml file

[alt text http://aliaydin.com.tr/exXml.jpg](http://aliaydin.com.tr/exXml.jpg)

this code doesn't work for I want

```
XElement zXml = new XElement("Days",           
           from g in listKD
           select new XElement("Day",
                        new XAttribute("id", g.Day),
                        new XElement("clock",
                        new XAttribute("id", g.c),
                      new XElement("s1", g.s1),
                      new XElement("s2", g.s2),
                      new XElement("s3", g.s3)
                      )));

        ZXml.Save("abc.xml");
```

Thanks...

Comment: What exactly DOES zXml.Save(...) produce? I understand there is a problem...but not sure what that problem is.

Comment: Watch out for your variable names; in your list, the "day" is lower case, while in the Linq-to-XML, you use g.Day - what is it now?? Lower- or uppercase - names **ARE** case-sensitive! Same goes for s1, s2, s3

Comment: You are creating a `<Day>` element for each item in `listKD`. You probably want to group elements having the same day into a single `<Day>` element and Marc Gravell has provided the answer.

Answer (score 10):

I think you haven't grouped by day; perhaps something like:

```
var el = new XElement("Days",
    from z in listKD
    group z by z.day into tmp
    select new XElement("Day",
        new XAttribute("id", tmp.Key),
        from item in tmp
        select new XElement("clock",
            new XAttribute("id", item.c),
            new XElement("s1", item.S1),
            new XElement("s2", item.S2),
            new XElement("s3", item.S3))
            ));
string s = el.ToString(); // or save etc
```

---

Update re comment; to reverse it, something like:

```
        XElement parsed = XElement.Parse(s);
        var newList = (from day in parsed.Elements("Day")
                       from clock in day.Elements("clock")
                       select new zil
                       {
                           day = (string)day.Attribute("id"),
                           c = (string)clock.Attribute("id"),
                           S1 = (string)clock.Element("S1"),
                           S2 = (string)clock.Element("S2"),
                           S3 = (string)clock.Element("S3")
                       }).ToList();
```

To filter to a specific day:

```
                       from day in parsed.Elements("Day")
                       where (string)day.Attribute("id") == "Mon"
                       from clock in day.Elements("clock")
                       ...
```

Comment: If only I had found this yesterday... Nice and simple solution to a problem that I had to solve by looping over the list.

Comment: Ok. How can I read the clock and [s1,s2,s3,s1...] from xml file for day. examp day=mon...

Answer (score 0):

```
   [XmlArray("Zils"), XmlArrayItem("Zil", typeof(zil))]
   public List<zil> listKD = new List<zil>();
```